# Atualizar FTP sem que o arquivo seja removido enquanto substitui

Tags: linux, ftp, centos

O `FTP` sempre que você envia um arquivo ele é inutilizável por alguns milissegundos, até que o arquivo inteiro esteja no local. O problema disso é que o arquivo por alguns milissegundos não existe ou está corrompido, o que faz com que arquivos de `include()` parem de funcionar durante alguns instantes.

Existe alguma forma de atualizar um arquivo e exista como ele recuperar um backup DURANTE ESSES "milissegundos"?

**Eu pensei numa solução**, porém não tenho muitos conhecimentos para fazer isso e não soube pesquisar sobre isso e acredito que deva já existir alguma solução, *não é possível que só eu tenha este problema*!

O nginx/php-fpm diz, por exemplo:

```
Call to undefined function minha_funcao()
```

Isso ocorre durantes esses poucos minutos que o arquivo seja substituído, mas que é suficiente para lotar os logs e também suficiente para perder visitas.

Minha ideia seria haver algum "backup".

Se "include.php" não existe então obtêm do "backup/include.php". Quando concluir o envio do "include.php", então copia o "include.php" (que não tem problema copiar) e envia para o "backup/include.php" (que ninguém está usando agora).

**Porém, não faço a minima ideia de:**

1. Como mover os arquivos verificando que não estão sendo usados (talvez pela data de modificação? Mas...)
2. Como apontar um "include()" alternativo ou seja, como fazer com que use o backup ou não.

E....

**Existe algum software que já faz isso?**

Comment: Suba e renomeie, muito mais rápido. Faça upload como arquivo.new, e quando concluir, apague o velho e renomeie o novo para o nome certo. Não vai evitar que por um breve instante fique indisponivel, mas é rápido o suficiente pra maioria dos casos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente se faz as mudanças com o sistema  pausado, sem execuções. Porque muitas vezes um update pode modificar também o banco de dados, regras de autenticação, etc. Então nesses casos mais críticos, é mais recomendado interromper todos os acessos.

Alternativamente, para casos menores onde não precisa necessariamente derrubar nenhuma conexão, poderia criar um espelho desse sistema dentro do mesmo servidor. Então sempre faria os updates no "espelho" que está "dormindo".

## Técnica com DocumentRoot

Exemplo, no Apache o site original está no diretório

```
/www/site/
```

O espelho, ou seja, uma cópia exata de todos esses arquivos do original estão numa outra pasta

```
/www/mirror/site/
```

Suponha que nesse momento o site está rodando com 200 conexões simultâneas e vc não tem loadbalance nem nada. Tudo que tem é um só servidor. Então tem que se virar com o que tem.

Você precisa atualizar 200 arquivos, mas sem interromper nada e tampouco causar corrompimento de dados.

Então o que poderia fazer é atualizar os arquivos no diretório do espelho

```
/www/mirror/site/
```

Quando completar, vai no Apache e muda o `DocumentRoot` para o local do espelho

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
#DocumentRoot "/www/site/"
DocumentRoot "/www/mirror/site/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Salve a alteração e dá um reload ou restart.

Agora o site já estará rodando sob o sistema com os arquivos atualziados.

Isso é apenas uma de diversas técnicas e tem uns pontos a se observar como possível conflito com algum outro sistema que estiver dependendo do local original do `DocumentRoot`. Também pode ter alguma perda com dados de cache. Mas são normalmente perdas pequenas que se recuperam nas primeiras execuções. Apenas esteja atento a dependências que podem causar conflitos, mas num ambiente em condições normais, não tem problemas.

Note que também haverá perda de conexões devido ao restart no Apache.

## Técnica com DirectoryIndex

Outro modo menos invasivo que segue a mesma lógica da troca do document root, é fazer isso mudando apenas o `htaccess`. Mas isso vai depender de como está a estrutura dos arquivos do sistema. Se estiver bem organizado pode realizar o mesmo esquema mencionado acima, porém usando somente o `htaccess`, sem precisar reiniciar o Apache.

A lógica é simples, normalmente o sistema tem apenas o arquivo `index.php` na pasta pública. Você pode ter um segundo arquivo, vamos chamar de `foo.php`.

No `htaccess`, bastaria trocar o `DirectoryIndex` para esse outro arquivo `foo.php`.
O arquivo `foo.php` inclui os arquivos do diretório do espelho.

Tudo que precisa fazer é seguir a mesma lógica do exemplo do `virtualhost`, só que ao invés de mecher diretamente no Apache, mudaria apenas o `DiretoryIndex`. Um simples upload do `htaccess` já faria a troca de um diretório para outro.

E assim você segue alternadamente. No próximo update, você faz as mudanças no diretório que está "dormindo".

<sub>obs: Nos exemplos usei Apache e PHP por serem mais populares mas pode ser aplicado em qualquer outro ambiente.</sub>